# How to recover Go timer from web-server restart (or code refresh/upgrade)?

Tags: timer, go, goji

Consider a web service, for instance, where user can make an API request to start a task at certain scheduled time. Task definition and scheduled time are persisted in a database.
First approach I came up with is to start a Go timer and wait for the timer to expire in a Goroutine (not blocking the request). This goroutine, after time expiration, will also fire another API request to start executing the task.

Now the problem arises when this service is redeployed. For zero downtime deployment I am using [Einhorn](https://github.com/stripe/einhorn.git) with [goji](https://github.com/zenazn/goji.git). After code reload, obviously both timer goroutine and timer-expiration-handler goroutine dies. Is there any way to recover Go timer after code reload?

Another problem I am struggling with is to allow the user to interrupt the timer (once its started). Go timer has [Stop](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Stop) to facilitate this. But since this is a stateless API, when the `\interrupt` request comes in service doesn't have context of timer channel. And it seems its not possible to marshal the channel (returned from [NewTimer](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#NewTimer)) to disk/db.

Its also very well possible that I am not looking at the problem from correct perspective. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'd use an external task queue service to do this, to keep this isolated from the service itself.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that's commonly used is to schedule the task outside your app, for example using crontab or systemd timers.

For example using crontab:

```
# run every 30 minutes
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/curl --head http://localhost/cron?key=something-to-verify-local-job >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Using an external task queue is also a valid option like @Not_a_Golfer mentioned but more complicated.

Comment: But then all scheduled cronjobs (still waiting) would be gone in case there is any hardware failure or server reboot. To avoid that I would need to create some sort of registry where all pending cronjobs are registered.